# Xpath multiple condition on same node

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a xml structure like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result>
   <node>
      <field value="79055_v01" name="Id" />
   </node>
   <node>
      <field value="79055" name="Id" />
   </node>
   <node>
      <field value="79155" name="Id" />
   </node>
   <node>
      <field value="811" name="Id" />
   </node>
   <node>
      <field value="811_v16" name="Id" />
      <field value="811" name="abc" />
   </node>
</Result>
```

I want to select the  which contain the field name 'Id' and the value '811'. What would be the xpath for this

So the correct xpath should return only

```
<node>
  <field value="811" name="Id" />
</node>
```

Tried

```
/Result/node[field/@name='Id' and field/@value='811']
```

but this returns two nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get `node` that has `field` with two required attributes, try:

```
/Result/node[field[@name='Id' and @value='811']]
```